# Задача найти три подряд одинаковых элемента

Tags: java

```
package com.company;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[]array={3, 7, 2,-5, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11};
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
            if ((array[i]*array[i+1] )&& (array[i+1]*array[i+2]>0)) {
                System.out.println("3 числа одного знака");

            }
         }
       }
      }
```

Comment: Добавьте код текстом. Картиночки, это издевательство

Comment: Сейчас добавлю код .

Comment: [можно](https://ideone.com/z49FB3) и ведь сразу `if (array[i]*array[i+1]*array[i+2] > 0) {`  .

Comment: не подойдет, так как -1*1*-1>0, ответ не подходит для решения задачи

Comment: а автору я рекомендую написать условия чётко: мы ищем не одинаковые элементы, а элементы с одинаковым знаком.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

возможно вы хотели написать так:

```
if ((array[i] * array[i+1] > 0) && (array[i+1] * array[i+2] > 0) )
```

чтобы сравнить как раз булевы значения.

Кстати, хочу сказать, если я правильно понимаю, то к концу цикла (при i равным length и length - 1) вы получите ошибку `IndexOutOfBoundsException` потому что при такой проверке выйдете за предел массива

Comment: Спасибо , именно так .

Comment: @Viktorov где вы тут видите работу за студентов? Я написал какой-то код с начала до конца?

Comment: Решать не надо ,  но подсказать можно .

Comment: @user7340622 вот я и подсказал) Вроде правильно. Не забудьте цикл сделать до array.length - 2

Comment: @user7340622 если ответ помог - щелкните галку слева от ответа)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать как-то так (но лучше не надо так делать :D ):

```
IntStream.range(1, array.length - 1)
    .filter(i -> Math.abs(IntStream.rangeClosed(i - 1, i + 1)
                              .map(x -> array[x])
                              .mapToDouble(Math::signum).boxed()
                              .mapToInt(Double::intValue).sum()) == 3)
    .mapToObj(i -> new int[]{array[i - 1], array[i], array[i + 1]})
    .map(Arrays::toString)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```